# What is the use of test directory in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been using android studio for some time.(still learning) and till date i haven't used the java files in the test folders. i.e the one's marked here :-

[image: diagram]

1. Is it necessary for a project or can we just delete those files?
2. If it is necessary, what is its use and how can we use it ? (any reference would be great).

If anyone could rephrase the question in a better way,it would be better.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are for tests. The `androidTest` is for instrumented tests while the `test` folder is for unit tests. You could delete them if you do not plan on using it, but it also does not harm your project.

See here [Test Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html)